# Hiding the closest div with the specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an application in which mimics desktop style application windows that open, minimize and close. I've managed to get them to expand and collapse, but I am unable to get the to close, and I can't figure out why. I need to be able to close the current div by clicking a button, see code / eg. below.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $("form.common").first().show();
             $(".expand").click(function () {
                 $(this).parents().next("form.common").show();
             })
             $(".collapse").click(function () {
                 $(this).parents().next("form.common").hide();
             });
             $(".close").click(function () {
                 $(this).parents().next("div.module").hide();
             });
    });
 </srcipt>
 <div id="task_manager" class="module"> <!-- Need the x with class close to hide this div-->
 <h3>Task Manager</h3> <!-- This header and below icons are shown when minimized-->
<div class="module_actions">
    <span class="icons_small right close">X</span>
    <span class="icons_small right collapse">-</span>
    <span class="icons_small right expand">+</span> 
</div>  
<form class="common">
    <fieldset>
     <legend> Some Titlee/legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Can anyone see why this is not hiding the div?
THanks,

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Other wise your code should work. Also by the way use closest(''.module_actions') instead of `parents()`

Comment: @PSL, there were no console errors but using .closest worked for me, thanks!!!

Comment: in that case you have more code than what you showed.. That is why parents() did not work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question:

```
$(".close").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div.module").hide();
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/kZBzu/3/)**

Also you should change your calls to `parents()` to just `parent()` so you just go up one level in the DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

You had a missing `<` in `<legend> Some Titlee/legend>`, after that it works.

Check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kZBzu/1/)**

Comment: @Mark, ok. But does the demo do what you want?

Comment: @PSL No, the close action doesn't work with the code in the question, see http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/kZBzu/4/, `.module` is an ancestor, not a sibling of an ancestor

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
  $(".close").click(function () {
       $(this).parent().hide();
   });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aecX/)
**Doc :** [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)