# Find closest div with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the DOM structure as

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subContent">
</div>
<div class="subContent">
</div>
```

I want to select `<div class="subContent">` on enter event of input box which is closest to the input box.

```
$('#search').on('keypress', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('#wrapper').nextAll('.subContent').first()
```

That way you can change it to use classes

Comment: `#wrapper` has no siblings

Comment: should be `$(this).closest("#content")` to grab the correct parent.

Comment: @scrappedcola I assumed that content is for the entire page and subcontent can be modularized

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help you

```
$("#search").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div.module").hide();
});
```

Possible duplicate of

[Hiding the closest div with the specified class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936200/hiding-the-closest-div-with-the-specified-class)

Comment: You realize that he is looking for the closest sibling to a parent div and not the closest parent right? Your answer doesn't answer the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:-

```
 <html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="search" />
            <div class="subContent" style = 'background-color:red;'>div1</div>
            <div class="subContent" style = 'background-color:red;'>div2</div>
            <div class="subContent" style = 'background-color:red;'>div3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </html>
    <script>
    $('#search').on('keypress', function(){
        $(this).next().css( "background-color", "blue" );
    });
    </script>
```